# how can select last message from messages list like whatsapp?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables, tbl_msg and tbl_details.(Like the photo below)
I want to select the last message of each chat, like the image embedded with SQL, such as WhatsApp and Telegram chat lists.(sql code).
please help me. thank's

[image: table's]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be one option:

```
select *
from tbl_msg a join tbl_msg_details b on b.msg_id = a.msg_id
where b.details_id = (select max(c.details_id)
                      from tbl_msg_details c
                      where c.msg_id = b.msg_id  
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is window functions:

```
select md.*
from (select md.*,
             row_number() over (partition by msg_id order by time_st desc) as seqnum
      from tbl_msg_details md
     ) md
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  You do not need `tbl_msg` unless there are columns from the table you want in the result set.

Also, it is unclear if the "last message" is based on the time column or the id column.  This uses the time column, but you can -- of course -- use the id if that is your definition of "last".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a "group by" and an "HAVING c.details_id = MAX(c.details_id)" it's better no ?

Like that :

```
select *
from tbl_msg a join tbl_msg_details b on b.msg_id = a.msg_id
group by c.details_id
HAVING c.details_id = MAX(c.details_id)
```